# Local notification fire date back up

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which i have implemented the local notifications concept. It is working fine. Let suppose I have set 5 notifications at different times. When first two notifications has been happened. But i didn't check it. Now when third notification rings, i viewed it. Now Is it possible to get the date time when first two alarms had. I need the date time for those notifications which the user has not seen.

Comment: Seems to me if you requested the notifications, you should be able to remember when they were.

Comment: Yup i have back up for all the fire dates..But I want only those date time which the user has not viewed due to some problem or may be he/she was busy.

Comment: this is tricky, because you should set the time for the notification. so you can set the time in a global variable while the method invokes and access the variable from everywhere you want. 

These links might help you. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13

Comment: Can't you track when the user views the notification (if he doesn't simply dismiss it)?

Answer (score 0):

as Hot Licks mentioned, when the notification has fired, you would check it in the app delegate did receive notifcation method against a list of 'waiting to be fired' notification that you store.
You then check on launch if there are any local events listed that do not match the current array of 'to be fired' notifcation. 
iterate through:

```
NSArray *localEvents= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```